# Failed to load class of driverClassName mongodb.jdbc.MongoDriver

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data, spring-data-jpa, hikaricp

Can someone please help me out. I am suck here for 2 days now. I am working on spring boot with access to two(2) data-sources. The application using HikariCp to connect to Postgresql and Mongodb, but I am getting the mongodb error. If I point the mongodb to another database (like Mysql or so) it will work but not with mongodb.

## DataSourceOne

```
@Configuration
@EnableJpaRepositories(
        basePackages = "com.deanace.oauth2.repository.datasourceOne",
        entityManagerFactoryRef = "entityManagerFactoryBeanOne",
        transactionManagerRef = "transactionManagerOne"
)
public class DataSourceOne {

    @Value("${spring.datasource.one.driverClassName}")
    private String driver;

    @Value("${spring.datasource.one.url}")
    private String url;

    @Value("${spring.datasource.one.username}")
    private String username;

    @Value("${spring.datasource.one.password}")
    private String password;

    @Bean
    public DataSource DataSourceOne(){
        HikariConfig config = new HikariConfig();
        config.setDriverClassName(driver);
        config.setJdbcUrl(url);
        config.setUsername(username);
        config.setPassword(password);
        config.setAutoCommit(true);
        return new HikariDataSource(config);
    }

    @Bean
    public PlatformTransactionManager transactionManagerOne(){
        return new JpaTransactionManager(entityManagerFactoryBeanOne().getObject());
    }

    @Bean
    public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactoryBeanOne() {
        HibernateJpaVendorAdapter jpaVendorAdapter = new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter();

        LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactoryBean = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
        entityManagerFactoryBean.setJpaVendorAdapter(jpaVendorAdapter);
        entityManagerFactoryBean.setDataSource(DataSourceOne());
        entityManagerFactoryBean.setPackagesToScan("com.deanace.oauth2.entities");
        return entityManagerFactoryBean;
    }
}
```

## DataSourceTwo

```
@Configuration
@EnableJpaRepositories(
        basePackages = "com.deanace.oauth2.repository.datasourceTwo",
        entityManagerFactoryRef = "entityManagerFactoryBeanTwo",
        transactionManagerRef = "transactionManagerTwo"
)
public class DataSourceTwo {

    @Value("${spring.datasource.mongodb.driverClassName}")
    private String driver;

    @Value("${spring.datasource.mongodb.url}")
    private String url;

    @Value("${spring.data.mongodb.username}")
    private String username;

    @Value("${spring.data.mongodb.password}")
    private String password;

    @Bean
    public DataSource DataSourceTwo(){
        HikariConfig config = new HikariConfig();
        config.setDriverClassName(driver);
        config.setJdbcUrl(url);
        config.setUsername(username);
        config.setPassword(password);
        config.setAutoCommit(true);
        return new HikariDataSource(config);
    }

    @Bean
    public PlatformTransactionManager transactionManagerTwo(){
        return new JpaTransactionManager(entityManagerFactoryBeanTwo().getObject());
    }

    @Bean
    public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactoryBeanTwo() {
        HibernateJpaVendorAdapter jpaVendorAdapter = new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter();

        LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactoryBean = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
        entityManagerFactoryBean.setJpaVendorAdapter(jpaVendorAdapter);
        entityManagerFactoryBean.setDataSource(DataSourceTwo());
        entityManagerFactoryBean.setPackagesToScan("com.deanace.oauth2.entities");
        return entityManagerFactoryBean;
    }
}
```

## application.properties

```
    spring.application.name=spring-security-oauth2
    spring.datasource.type=com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource
    # suppress inspection "SpringBootApplicationProperties" for whole file
    server.port=8080
    # ===============================
    # DATASOURCE
    # ===============================
    # DataSource (Postgresql offline).
    spring.datasource.one.driverClassName=org.postgresql.Driver
    spring.datasource.one.url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/application1
    spring.datasource.one.username=postgres
    spring.datasource.one.password=password

    #mongodb mongodb.jdbc.MongoDriver
    spring.datasource.one.driverClassName=org.MongoDriver.Driver
    spring.datasource.one.url=jdbc:mongo://localhost:5432/application2
    spring.data.mongodb.username=mongodb
    spring.data.mongodb.password=password
    spring.data.mongodb.host=localhost
    spring.data.mongodb.port=27017
    spring.data.mongodb.database=application2
```

## Error

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactoryBeanTwo' defined in class path resource [com/deanace/oauth2/persistence/DataSourceTwo.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean]: Factory method 'entityManagerFactoryBeanTwo' threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'DataSourceTwo' defined in class path resource [com/deanace/oauth2/persistence/DataSourceTwo.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [javax.sql.DataSource]: Factory method 'DataSourceTwo' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.RuntimeException: Failed to load class of driverClassName mongodb.jdbc.MongoDriver
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:599) ~[spring-beans-4.3.14.RELEASE.jar:4.3.14.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1173) ~[spring-beans-4.3.14.RELEASE.jar:4.3.14.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1067) ~[spring-beans-4.3.14.RELEASE.jar:4.3.14.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:513) ~[spring-beans-4.3.14.RELEASE.jar:4.3.14.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:483) ~[spring-beans-4.3.14.RELEASE.jar:4.3.14.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306) ~[spring-beans-4.3.14.RELEASE.jar:4.3.14.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230) ~[spring-beans-4.3.14.RELEASE.jar:4.3.14.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302) ~[spring-beans-4.3.14.RELEASE.jar:4.3.14.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197) ~[spring-beans-4.3.14.RELEASE.jar:4.3.14.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1080) ~[spring-context-4.3.14.RELEASE.jar:4.3.14.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:857) ~[spring-context-4.3.14.RELEASE.jar:4.3.14.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:543) ~[spring-context-4.3.14.RELEASE.jar:4.3.14.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:122) ~[spring-boot-1.5.10.RELEASE.jar:1.5.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:693) [spring-boot-1.5.10.RELEASE.jar:1.5.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:360) [spring-boot-1.5.10.RELEASE.jar:1.5.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:303) [spring-boot-1.5.10.RELEASE.jar:1.5.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1118) [spring-boot-1.5.10.RELEASE.jar:1.5.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1107) [spring-boot-1.5.10.RELEASE.jar:1.5.10.RELEASE]
    at com.deanace.oauth2.SpringSecurityOauth2Application.main(SpringSecurityOauth2Application.java:64) [classes/:na]
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean]: Factory method 'entityManagerFactoryBeanTwo' threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'DataSourceTwo' defined in class path resource [com/deanace/oauth2/persistence/DataSourceTwo.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [javax.sql.DataSource]: Factory method 'DataSourceTwo' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.RuntimeException: Failed to load class of driverClassName mongodb.jdbc.MongoDriver
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:189) ~[spring-beans-4.3.14.RELEASE.jar:4.3.14.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:588) ~[spring-beans-4.3.14.RELEASE.jar:4.3.14.RELEASE]
    ... 18 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'DataSourceTwo' defined in class path resource [com/deanace/oauth2/persistence/DataSourceTwo.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [javax.sql.DataSource]: Factory method 'DataSourceTwo' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.RuntimeException: Failed to load class of driverClassName mongodb.jdbc.MongoDriver
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:599) ~[spring-beans-4.3.14.RELEASE.jar:4.3.14.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1173) ~[spring-beans-4.3.14.RELEASE.jar:4.3.14.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1067) ~[spring-beans-4.3.14.RELEASE.jar:4.3.14.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:513) ~[spring-beans-4.3.14.RELEASE.jar:4.3.14.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:483) ~[spring-beans-4.3.14.RELEASE.jar:4.3.14.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306) ~[spring-beans-4.3.14.RELEASE.jar:4.3.14.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230) ~[spring-beans-4.3.14.RELEASE.jar:4.3.14.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302) ~[spring-beans-4.3.14.RELEASE.jar:4.3.14.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197) ~[spring-beans-4.3.14.RELEASE.jar:4.3.14.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassEnhancer$BeanMethodInterceptor.obtainBeanInstanceFromFactory(ConfigurationClassEnhancer.java:389) ~[spring-context-4.3.14.RELEASE.jar:4.3.14.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassEnhancer$BeanMethodInterceptor.intercept(ConfigurationClassEnhancer.java:361) ~[spring-context-4.3.14.RELEASE.jar:4.3.14.RELEASE]
    at com.deanace.oauth2.persistence.DataSourceTwo$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$cf32bb56.DataSourceTwo(<generated>) ~[classes/:na]
    at com.deanace.oauth2.persistence.DataSourceTwo.entityManagerFactoryBeanTwo(DataSourceTwo.java:62) ~[classes/:na]
    at com.deanace.oauth2.persistence.DataSourceTwo$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$cf32bb56.CGLIB$entityManagerFactoryBeanTwo$1(<generated>) ~[classes/:na]
    at com.deanace.oauth2.persistence.DataSourceTwo$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$cf32bb56$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$12340b71.invoke(<generated>) ~[classes/:na]
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invokeSuper(MethodProxy.java:228) ~[spring-core-4.3.14.RELEASE.jar:4.3.14.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassEnhancer$BeanMethodInterceptor.intercept(ConfigurationClassEnhancer.java:358) ~[spring-context-4.3.14.RELEASE.jar:4.3.14.RELEASE]
    at com.deanace.oauth2.persistence.DataSourceTwo$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$cf32bb56.entityManagerFactoryBeanTwo(<generated>) ~[classes/:na]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_152]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_152]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_152]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_152]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:162) ~[spring-beans-4.3.14.RELEASE.jar:4.3.14.RELEASE]
    ... 19 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [javax.sql.DataSource]: Factory method 'DataSourceTwo' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.RuntimeException: Failed to load class of driverClassName mongodb.jdbc.MongoDriver
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:189) ~[spring-beans-4.3.14.RELEASE.jar:4.3.14.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:588) ~[spring-beans-4.3.14.RELEASE.jar:4.3.14.RELEASE]
    ... 41 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Failed to load class of driverClassName mongodb.jdbc.MongoDriver
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig.setDriverClassName(HikariConfig.java:323) ~[HikariCP-2.5.1.jar:na]
    at com.deanace.oauth2.persistence.DataSourceTwo.DataSourceTwo(DataSourceTwo.java:43) ~[classes/:na]
    at com.deanace.oauth2.persistence.DataSourceTwo$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$cf32bb56.CGLIB$DataSourceTwo$0(<generated>) ~[classes/:na]
    at com.deanace.oauth2.persistence.DataSourceTwo$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$cf32bb56$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$12340b71.invoke(<generated>) ~[classes/:na]
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invokeSuper(MethodProxy.java:228) ~[spring-core-4.3.14.RELEASE.jar:4.3.14.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassEnhancer$BeanMethodInterceptor.intercept(ConfigurationClassEnhancer.java:358) ~[spring-context-4.3.14.RELEASE.jar:4.3.14.RELEASE]
    at com.deanace.oauth2.persistence.DataSourceTwo$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$cf32bb56.DataSourceTwo(<generated>) ~[classes/:na]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_152]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_152]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_152]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_152]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:162) ~[spring-beans-4.3.14.RELEASE.jar:4.3.14.RELEASE]
    ... 42 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: mongodb.jdbc.MongoDriver
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381) ~[na:1.8.0_152]
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424) ~[na:1.8.0_152]
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:338) ~[na:1.8.0_152]
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357) ~[na:1.8.0_152]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig.setDriverClassName(HikariConfig.java:318) ~[HikariCP-2.5.1.jar:na]
    ... 53 common frames omitted
```

Or if anyone can help with another approach that can be of help. Thank in advance

Comment: what are your spring and mongodb versions?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, You are trying to use mongoDB with JDBC. I think this is  not a common practice use JDBC with mongoDB. However if you want to use this way,there is [unityJDBC](http://www.unityjdbc.com/mongojdbc/mongo_jdbc.php) , that you can use as JDBC driver. Also take a look at [this](https://spring.io/guides/gs/accessing-data-mongodb/).

Comment: @want2learn..Thanks for your response. I have tired it but is not working for me

Answer (score 0):

If you want to connect monogoDb with JDBC, you can add these two lines in **application.properties** file for connecting mongodb with JDBC and to exclude  autoconfiguration.

```
#connect mongodb with jdbc
spring.data.mongodb.uri=mongodb://localhost:27017/testDb\ 

#exclude jdbc autoconfiguration
spring.autoconfigure.exclude=org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceAutoConfiguration
```

Also put @EnableAutoConfiguration annotation in application's **main.class**

```
@EnableAutoConfiguration(exclude={DataSourceAutoConfiguration.class, XADataSourceAutoConfiguration.class})
```

Because the JPA auto configuration feature of the spring boot application attempts to establish database connection using JPA Datasource. The java class DataSourceAutoConfiguration is responsible for loading JPA DataSource. The auto configuration can be disabled by excluding DataSourceAutoConfiguration class from the spring boot context.